# How to get a value of data-attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I need to get the value of userid, data-attribute from a html table and put this value into a var, but I wanna to this action without click action.

```
  <table id="tblList">
    <tbody id="someTest">
      <tr data-userid="801992084067">
      <tr data-userid="451207954179">
      <tr data-userid="310896831399">
      <tr data-userid="863939754980">
      <tr data-userid="1123542226482">
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I have tried to do this like that, but the rowId is undefined.

```
 var rowId = $("#someTest tr").last().attr("[data-userid"]");
```

Comment: You may use $("#someTest tr").last().attr('data-userid'); OR even $('#someTest tr:last').attr('data-userid')

Comment: or `$("#someTest tr").last().data('userid');`

Comment: there's a typo `.attr("[data-userid"]");` should be `.attr("[data-userid]");`

Comment: or `$("#someTest tr:last-child").data('userid');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

only Remove `[]` :

```
 var rowId = $("#someTest tr").last().attr("data-userid");
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <title>This is test</title>
    
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="tblList">
    <tbody id="someTest">
      <tr data-userid="801992084067">
      <tr data-userid="451207954179">
      <tr data-userid="310896831399">
      <tr data-userid="863939754980">
      <tr data-userid="1123542226482">
    </tbody>
  </table>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            
$(document).ready(function(){
    
   var rowId = $("#someTest tr").last().attr("data-userid");
    alert(rowId);
       
})
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And how a get a specific userid?

Comment: @user6018902,   explain with an example please.

Comment: @user6018902 , for example if you want get first userid,you can use of `var rowId = $("#someTest tr").eq(0).attr("data-userid");` for For the second use `var rowId = $("#someTest tr").eq(1).attr("data-userid");`

Comment: I have to take a specific userid of the table depending on the row with the user that I change, in this part here,  when I want to change the value of the editet user in the table I need to get the userid of row that I  modified.

Comment: @user6018902,   what is inside tr tag that you want change? text or checkbox or ...

Comment: Yes, and I already have a object with edited value of row, but I don't know how to get the specific row to insert this 'new' value in the row that I select to edit. And a way to do this is using the data-userid from table, to know exact where to put the edited user information.

Answer (score 6):

Simply, you can manage data attribute & value in HTML tag using `data()` method of jQuery. Alternatively, you can use attr() method also,

```
var rowId = $("#someTest tr").last().data("userid");
```

Alternatively

```
var rowId = $("#someTest tr").last().attr("data-userid");
```

> .data() method is used to store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return
>   the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements.

**Initial HTML**

```
<button id="mybtn">MyButton</button>
```

**Add data-attribute with value**

```
$('button#mybtn').data('id',10);
```

Alternatively

```
$('button#mybtn').data('data-id',10);
```

**Reproduced HTML**

```
<button id="mybtn" data-id="10">MyButton</button>
```

**Get value from data-attribute**

```
alert($('button#mybtn').data('id')); //alerts 10
```

Alternatively

```
alert($('button#mybtn').attr('data-id')); //alerts 10
```

**Change value of data-attribute**

```
$('button#mybtn').data('id',15);
```

Alternatively

```
$('button#mybtn').attr('data-id',15);
```

**Reproduced HTML**

```
<button id="mybtn" data-id="15">MyButton</button>
```

**Remove data-attribute**
You can remove data attribute using `removeData()` method

```
$('button#mybtn').removeData('id');
```

Alternatively

```
$('button#mybtn').removeAttr('data-id');
```

**Reproduced HTML**

```
<button id="mybtn">MyButton</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you just have to remove the **square brackets**:

```js
var rowId = $("#someTest tr").last().attr("data-userid");
$('#rowidOutputAttr').text(rowId);
var rowId = $("#someTest tr").last().data("userid");
$('#rowidOutputData').text(rowId);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <table id="tblList">
    <tbody id="someTest">
      <tr data-userid="801992084067">
      <tr data-userid="451207954179">
      <tr data-userid="310896831399">
      <tr data-userid="863939754980">
      <tr data-userid="1123542226482">
    </tbody>
  </table>
    <div id=rowidOutputAttr></div>
    <div id=rowidOutputData></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

i also added en example with `.data()`